# Wi-fi driver broken after changing kernel

Tags: networking, drivers, kernel, broadcom

So I don't know which was it that caused this problem. Changing the kernel or accidentally deleting the connected device. But after that I can't connect to wi-fi and iwconfig shows no wireless extensions.

At this point I have switched back to multiple old/new kernels, tried to install bcmwl-kernel-source which is for my device and many other things. I dug around and saw that there is a bug for legacy mode users and therefore I applied a patch to the source bcmwl package and built a deb but still didn't work.

rfkill list all returns

```
0: sony-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: sony-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

In software and updates in the additional driver, the broadcom is the only one listed and it is installed and enabled. The main issue is whenever I try to install bcmwl-kernel-source it returns

```
installed bcmwl-kernel-source package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
Errors were encountered while processing:
 bcmwl-kernel-source
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

And it is not a hardware issue as I booted ubuntu from a boot usb and installed bcmwl there and it worked fine. I only option would be reinstall but I don't have time for that and is too much pain. Everything else works fine including ethernet and graphics card. Please help me

lspci -knn | grep Net -A3

```
lspci: Unable to load libkmod resources: error -12
07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [105b:e071]
08:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5209 PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:5209] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Sony Corporation RTS5209 PCI Express Card Reader [104d:90b8]
```

Comment: Please elaborate "changing kernel".

Comment: I installed a new kernel from the mainline. It was 5.4 I guess and I installed 5.5 or 5.6. Currently running on 5.6.18. Ubuntu LTS 20.04

Comment: This is expected. The driver doesn't build.

Comment: What do I do now?

Comment: Let's start from what is your hardware. Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mainline kernels are not necessarily supported by Broadcom proprietary drivers.

Especially when you install the latest mainline kernels.

The drivers need patches to support the newest kernels. Ubuntu maintainers didn't create them for the 5.5-5.6 kernels, because they are not supported.

Remove mainline kernels and boot with an official Ubuntu kernel. The driver should work. If it doesn't, reinstall it.

Comment: But I switch the kernel to an older kernel version(the one in which it used to work) and it still doesnt work. Is reinstall the only option now?

Comment: I think you can reinstall only `bcmwl-kernel-source`

Comment: That returns the same error stated above

Comment: How do you reinstall it? And what is the current kernel `uname -a`?

Comment: Ubuntu focal fossa 20.04 LTS and kernel is 5.6.18 from mainline. I tried reinstalling by running sudo apt-get --purge remove bcmwl-kernel-source which tries to update initramfs and then sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source which returns the errors in my question.

Comment: So boot with a supported Ubuntu kernel `5.4.0-xx`. It should work.

Comment: and should I install the bcmwl after booting into 5.4?

Comment: Maybe it will work. If it doesn't, then re-install. Also i suggest removing mainline kernels. `dkms` may try to build for them and fail.

Comment: I'm unable to boot into the 5. 4 kernels (I have 2). The screen has a message about Bluetooth hci0 and it keeps blinking and won't enter login screen

Comment: Then it means that you broke something else too.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH. I'm writing this answer right now while connected to my wi-fi. I'm so happy and so glad. It's been so many late nights that I've been searching for a solution and I can't believe this worked! Ik I might sound dumb and this might be some basic stuff but I'm a noob. But anyways, thank you so much and I couldn't be more grateful. The problem was solved after I removed the 5.6 and other kernels and wollah! It worked and the drivers were installed on their own. THANK YOU ONCE AGAIN @Pilot6